# How to stop/terminate the calling function in C++ but not the whole program similar to "return ;" behavior?

Tags: c++, return, inline, terminate

I would like to seek for your inputs regarding this problem on what could be the possible approaches.

A simple illustration of what i like to achieve is this.

**Behavior**

```
void foo(const std::string value){
    //Several lines above

    if( value.empty() ){
        ERROR_LOG("value is empty");
        return ; 
    }
    
    //Several lines below

}
```

I would like something similar but approach is like this below:

```
static inline check(bool pred, std::string message){
   if(!pred){
      ERROR_LOG("%s", message);  
      // The problem is the part after this,
      // How do I achieve to terminate only the calling function but not the whole program.
      std::terminate(); 
   }
}


void foo(const std::string value){
   // Several lines above
   check( !value.empty(), "Error, Value is empty" );
   // Several lines below
}
```

I would like to create a helper function called `check` for a readable code. Please note that the "Several lines" comment may indicate 300+ lines of code. The first method would surely work but I would like to achieve a similar result on a cleaner approach.

I have already tried the following exit(0), std::terminate(), abort() but all these would stop the entire program. Thanks

Comment: If you have a long-running "process" that you want to be able to break at any time, first of all you might want to put it in a thread. Secondly you might want to have some way to notify the thread that it should exit. Thirdly you need to check for this "exit" signal or notification in multiple places. And lastly it should just *return* like any normal function (with the `return` statement).

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for exceptions.

Comment: Your `check()` doesn't have any return type but it should (must). So, an alternative to the exception could be to give `check()` the return type `bool` where `return true;` means success and `return false;` means failed (or vice versa). Then, you could call `check()` in `foo()` with an `if(check(...))` and `return` from `foo()` if `check()` returned `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can mange it using Exceptions. Somethng like

```
static inline check(bool pred, std::string message){
   if(!pred){
      ERROR_LOG("%s", message);  
      throw new Exception("message");
   }
}


void foo(const std::string value){
   // Several lines above
   try
   {
        check( !value.empty(), "Error, Value is empty" );
        // Several lines below
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
        // manage your case here
   }
}
```

Of course using this pattern the Exception management could be done at any level of the call stack

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think this is a valid approach. I will wait for other replies if there are also solutions who does not use try-catch statements